# How to change the grub booting partition on SSD

Tags: boot-repair, grub-efi

Installed Ubuntu on SSD, but can't get the system to boot. Gparted shows that the EFI system partition with the boot flag is on /dev/nvme0n1p1 , but boot-repair finds grub in /dev/nvme0n1p2, and automatic repair just reinstalls grub in this second partition.

How can I repair this mismatch? Can I flag the nvme0n1p2 as the boot partition? Or should I rather try to install grub on nvme0n1p1 ? (if yes, how?)

Report from boot-repair (after repair)
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25682275/

The output of 
 [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"

is "EFI boot on HDD"

Which apparently says that the installation IS in EFI mode, but that it is on the HDD, which should not be (I want to install it on the SSD), but also is weird, as it is NOT booting, and it does not show any files in the HDD.

Comment: Neither grubx64.efi not shimx64.efi show in the EFI partition (nvme0n1p1) did you install ubuntu in efi mode?

Comment: I think I did. Method for checking this? These files do show up on nvme0n1p2 though right?

Comment: no they do not. they are the boot files. EFI boots from the EFI folder on the EFI system partition partition.  Their absence  suggests that ubuntu was installed in Legacy mode.

Comment: If that were the case, I should be able to boot the system when changing to Legacy right? Which is not the case...

Comment: no, legacy boot can not read a GPT partition table and requires a bootloader in the MBR, thus it would boot windows in efi mode

Comment: Apparently the report by boot-repair is not well suited for SSDs (nvme01.. see answer by Rod Smith in my other post). I understood now your suggestion on that post and copied and renamed /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. This did not solve the booting issue, although now Gparted can see and locate the SSD... (Secure boot disabled)

Comment: Bootinfoscript which is the first part of the Summary Report does not parse NVMe drives. Your ESP is on the NVMe drive. When you say `echo "EFI boot on HDD" ` it will not say SSD nor NVMe drive, it does not know difference. What brand/model system? And what video card/chip? Major parts of grub are in / both /boot folder & other folders. Only boot loader is in ESP which you have. If UEFI does not boot ubuntu entry, then you may need other boot parameters or have a video issue. You show nVidia, so may need nomodeset.

Comment: You may want to try putting my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive or CD-R. This should enable you to boot, at least temporarily. You can then either install GRUB manually `sudo grub-install` or install rEFInd's Debian package or PPA to get the system booting permanently. This procedure is not guaranteed to work, but if rEFInd works on an external medium, it should at least give you a temporary workaround and some breathing room.